# jQuery 1.8.1 .load html>body

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova

```
$("#loader").load(someurl, null, function ()
{
    var html = $("#loader").html(); 
    alert(html);  //works 
});
```

however,

```
$("#loader").load(someurl, "body", function ()
{
    var html = $("#loader").html(); 
    alert(html);  //does NOT work 
});
```

I try to fetch external host html data on phonegap/cordova.

`filetransfer.download` API does not work well for me for html fetching, and I found jQuery .load function works well and think it's uselful because file management isn't involved but only memory.

A problem is, since whole HTML is once load on some `$("#loader")`, css/style-sheet for `html.body` layer conflicts and messes.

Therefore, I try to fetch only body part of html
http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
.load( url [, data] [, complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)] )
```

however, `[, data]` option never works.

`"html>body"` does not work, or any selectors doen't seem to work.

Is this bug??

Answer (score 2):

The selector should be appended to the url (separated by a space).

```
$("#loader").load(someurl + ' body', function (){
    var html = $("#loader").html(); 
    alert(html);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, your code does not work either for my environment (iOS5 Safari+ cordova/phonegap2.0). Again, without <+ ' body'>, it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The data parameter is used in making the load request, if you want to filter content from the page you have to add the selector to the end of the url separated by a space.

```
$("#loader").load(someurl + ' body', function (){
    var html = $("#loader").html(); 
    alert(html);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I've got the idea, and the official documentation shall be fixed as you mention. Having said that,<someurl + ' body'> way does not work on my environment (iOS5 Safari+ cordova/phonegap2.0). So I think this might be a bug of jQuery framework for iOS safari.

Answer (score 1):

You can load only a portion of the page using the load method. You need to supply the selector in the first parameter. (see the `Loading Page Fragments` section on the [Load() api](http://api.jquery.com/load/))

```
$('#loader').load('ajax/test.html body',function(){
var html = $("#loader").html();
alert(html);

});
```